# Force Omniauth to use json for callback?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, omniauth

I'm attempting to integrate Omniauth into an API written in rails, to be used by an Android application. This means that I want to be able to handle the omniauth callback with JSON.

By default, Omniauth sends its callbacks to `/auth/:provider/callback`, is there a way that I can force Omniauth to instead send its callbacks to `/auth/:provider/callback.json`?

Answer (score 2):

You can specify format in action where handling callback:

```
# in route.rb
match '/auth/:provider/callback' => 'authentications#create'

# in authentications_controller.rb
class AuthenticationsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    # your code here
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { ... } # content to return
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: This would be the code to handle such a request, yes, but my problem is that by default Omniauth never sends any request that specify the format as json, it's always html.

Comment: No I haven't, where exactly would I put this?

Comment: Try to simulate authentication request to `/auth/:provider/callback` with `:content_type => :json, :accept => :json`

Comment: I don't think I quite explained the problem correctly. I know _how_ to make and respond to a json request, just not how to make the oauth providers request a json response for the callback

Answer (score 2):

I managed to do that by inspecting the request object on my rails backend.

When I make the request on my app, I add data on the submition defining the format:

```
format: "json"
```

And the omniauth then makes the callback for

```
/auth/:provider/callback
```

Wich in my case matches

```
sessions#create
```

as an HTML request. But once there, if you look at your request object in rails, and search for the omniauth.params hash you'll see that one of the values there is the format passed on tha data of the initial request:

```
"omniauth.params"=>{"format"=>"json", "provider"=>"facebook", "code"=>"..."}
```

Its a mather of you searching for this "format"=>"json" and doing a render json as an answear.

I hope it solves your problem.

Comment: If you have any problem accessing the right param, I do it like this: request.env['omniauth.params']['format'] and it gives me json.

Answer (score 0):

```
# app/controllers/users_controller.rb
def authenticate
  @credentials = request.env['omniauth.auth']
  render json: @credentials
end

# config/routes.rb
get '/auth/:provider/callback', to: 'users#authenticate', as: 'user_auth'
```

And then all requests made to `/auth/:provider/callback` will return a JSON response by default.